Missing position (lat/lon) in ADSB data
I would like to ask if anyone has encountered latitude longitude (Data Item 021/130) missing in ADSB data, specifically in asterix cat 21. In addition to the mandador entries, there is also geometric and barometric altitude or flight identifiers available in the data, but the lat/long position is missing. Is it possible for the pilot to disable the sending of the lat/lon position in the ADS-B data?

What brand/model of receiver do you use and which ASTERIX Cat 21 edition does it provide?

ADS-B transmitters can transmit NO-Position messages (FTC=0) if the source of position data does not provide position data. This can happen when GPS is unavailable (e.g. due to jamming). In some installations it may be possible that the pilot switches the position data off. This is however non-standard.

Wow, can it really happen that the pilot switches off only the position sent in ADSB? What does the aircraft have to be equipped with for the pilot to be able to do that? Thank you for your answer.

On some state aircraft it is possible to switch ADS-B position. It requires an additional switch/controller in the cockpit. Very rare to see this. I think it is more likely that you have seen a case where GPS position was not available to the transponder. If you are not too far from a war zone (e.g. Ukraine), it could well be an effect of GPS jamming. Or there can be faulty logic in the ADS-B receiver, and there are a few other cases that may trigger this in a well functioning receiver. What make/model of receiver do you work with. Which Asterix 21 edition?
